# Come to think of it, who did put the bop in the bop shoo bop shoo bop?

Tags: voice, history, lyrics

There have been "la la la"s and nonsense lyrics in music since ... well, since a long time back. Why, who could forget that sixteenth-century classic "[Nos Galan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VRqTN0IVV0U)"? And [Nigunim](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-chVjDxy_6k) have been part of Jewish tradition since at least the early 1700s. And [Svara](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1ek4siKqn4) has been around for a couple of thousand years or so.

But do scat and Doo-Wop-style syllablizations (if I may coin a term) find their origins in earlier traditions, or are they distinct unto themselves? Where do they come from?

---

And for anyone unfamiliar with the song quoted in the title:

Comment: Looks like one reasonable origin theory is the syllables evolved from a capella vocals originally intended to imitate the sounds of instruments: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doo-wop

Comment: @ToddWilcox Interesting. It suggests, to me at least, that scat and doo-wop might have developed independently of each other.

Comment: Well, whoever it was, I'd like to shake his hand

Comment: Maybe someone who was lost for words?  Scatology comes to mind...

Answer (score 1):

I think folk music presents a plausible, partial origin...

```
OLD CHIZZUM (CHISHOLM) TRAIL

Come along, boys, and listen to my tale,
I'll tell you of my troubles on the Old Chizzum Trail.

Coma-ti yi yippy, yippy yea, yippy yea,
Coma-ti yi yippy, yippy yea.
```

```
Whisky in the Jar
...
Mush-a ring dum-a do dum-a da
Whack for my daddy-o
Whack for my daddy-o
There's whiskey in the jar
```

```
Paddy works on the railway
...
chorus:
Fil-i-me-oo-ree-eye-ri-ay
Fil-i-me-oo-ree-eye-ri-ay
Fil-i-me-oo-ree-eye-ri-ay
To work upon the railway
```

The last one is a nice example of whole lines/verses of nonsense.

I like the folk comparison, because the rhythms are usually snappy. Of course they don't have the back beat like Doo-Wop, but it seems a closer connection that la, la, la from madrigals.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered your own question.  Yes, 'Fa-la-la' and 'Nonnie-nonnie-no' have been around for a long time.  Those are the origins.  Jazz has added its own flavour.

Answer (score -1):

interesting question! never wasted a thought about it.

Maybe it comes from singing and playing instruments in different attacking styles, using the tongue, lips or larynx:

voice: a_a_a_, ahhhh, lalalala, a/a/a/

flute: du____, hu____, dup, dup,

trumpet: ta____, Da_____, tatata, tut, tut,

sax/clarinet: be-bop, be-bop